# Is the used Nikon Nikkor 18-200mm lens I bought broken?

Tags: lens, nikon, zoom, troubleshooting

I bought the 18-200mm Nikon lens used through a reputable vendor through the mail. I purchased insurance just in case the lens did not work or was damaged in shipping.

I'm not a professional but I know my way around my cameras. I did my research to make sure this lens would compliment my older D50. The reports I read seemed like a match made in heaven! I couldn't wait to take pics of the wild life in my bird sanctuary.

However, I cannot get it to focus when taking pictures thirty yards away. The focus ring that reads 200 down to 18 only moves between 135 and 30(?).  It makes a creaky noise when it is attempting to focus.  Pics I take ten to fifteen feet away have good detail. But they are not sharp and crisp like the photos I get from my other lenses.

Am I missing something? Is the lens broken?  Any help is appreciated before I file a return.

Comment: `The **focus** ring that reads 200 down to 18` Thats not a _focus_ ring thats a _zoom_ ring - are you sure you're operating it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I have the [AF-S Nikkor 18-200 1:3.5-5.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_AF-S_DX_VR_Zoom-Nikkor_18-200mm_f/3.5-5.6G_IF-ED) which I believe is the same lens as you.

[image: AF-S Nikkor 18-200 1:3.5-5.6]

Mine is paired with a D90 body and I have none of the issues that you have described.

Can you try this simple test:

1. Remove lens from camera
2. Ensure 18mm lock is released
3. Ensure focus switch on M (Manual) instead of M/A (Manual/Automatic)
4. Move the lens between the 18mm and 200mm focal points - this should be a fluid move with no sound
5. The focus ring should be able to move between infinity and 0.5 with the same fluid movements

If you experience none of the above, then I would say contact the seller and see if they will honor a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The zoom ring should move freely between 18 and 200.  The only thing to prevent that is the zoom lock, and that should only engage when the lens is at 18mm.

Focusing should be fairly silent, so creaky noise doesn't sound good.

The lens is pretty sharp for a super zoom, better than your average kit lens, so images should be sharp.  When you focus, does the green focus light come on in your viewfinder?

Sounds like a problem with the lens.